# Split a table into columns and group by date

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a summary  table for the table below. What I want to do is create new columns called `costA`,`costB`,`budgetA`,`budgetB`,`date`. Below is my input table. Basically new columns and group by date. Can someone suggest what would be the best approach to do it? My lame way of doing it was splitting into table tables and then join

```
Date    Source  Cost    Budget
01/01/2021  A   651.4626049 437.3988105
01/01/2021  B   603.4283224 523.5489139
01/03/2021  A   478.8275428 281.9939502
01/04/2021  A   938.0108057 275.8212764
01/05/2021  B   709.1229438 50.20628655
01/05/2021  A   665.9466426 448.2541946
01/07/2021  B   668.8941316 87.52829458
01/08/2021  A   503.8861367 365.8068408
01/09/2021  A   791.724207  142.4834237
01/09/2021  B   625.2508126 239.4462894
01/09/2021  A   604.1126629 751.573689
01/12/2021  B   774.6866392 18.30540524
01/13/2021  A   288.4762242 753.7628064
01/14/2021  A   882.1594945 422.7278152
01/15/2021  B   11.06688457 588.0375262
01/16/2021  A   150.1645301 349.6478647
01/17/2021  B   817.3673465 81.62528667
01/18/2021  A   936.6920639 845.5250291
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you are after - desired results would help - however if I understand your question you just need to pivot your source rows into columns. you can do that with a *conditional case and aggregation* like:

```
select date, 
    max(case source when 'A' then cost end  ) CostA,
    max(case source when 'B' then cost end  ) CostB,
    max(case source when 'A' then Budget end) BudgetA,
    max(case source when 'B' then Budget end) BudgetB
from t
group by date
```